# Grocery CRUD multi select drop down list

Tags: codeigniter, grocery-crud

I want to add a multi select drop down to my gc add form.i could generate a single select drop down using set relation.but i dont know how to make it multi select drop down.please help,thank you! 
  `$crud->set_relation('color','tbl_color','color');`
with this  i could get a single selection drop down list.

Answer (score 0):

checkout the documentation for relation_n_n.

http://www.grocerycrud.com/documentation/options_functions/set_relation_n_n

Answer (score 0):

add the following to your code after `$crud->set_relation`,

```
$this->db->select('*');
$querydata = $this->db->get('tbl_color')->result(); // to get whole table values

$resultarray = array();  // defines a new array

foreach ($querydata as $result) {

$resultarray[$result->color] = $result->color; //initializing table values to the array 

}

$crud->field_type('color', 'multiselect', $resultarray); // setting multiple select
```

Hope this will help, because its working fine for me.